# Restrict user from opening new tab in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to restrict a user from opening a new tab in mvc application, we are using azure active directory authentication so by default it uses cookie & we can't disable cookie.

In order to store data we are using session to store class details and its persisted throughout the application however a new tab creates an issue as the session details are getting shared, what we can do to resolve this issue any code link will surely help.

code using AAD

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);  // Authentication type is cookies

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
               {
                   AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
                            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

                      // Here the code all about certification & access token

                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   }
               }
        });
}
```